# How to set an XSLT boolean variable to true if an attribute is empty or doesn't exist?

Tags: xslt

When an attribute is missing or is empty, I want my variable set to `false()`.

**XML:**

```
<cd name="One" />
<cd name="Two" incollection=""/>
<cd name="Three" incollection="true"/>
```

**XSL:**

```
<!-- this will only set to false when attribute is missing -->
<xsl:variable name="incollection" select="boolean(@incollection)"/>
<!-- this will set to false both when attribute is missing or is empty-->
<xsl:variable name="incollection2" select="boolean(@incollection) or @incollection=''"/>
```

Although the second expression works for me, I was wondering whether there was a better and more idiomatic way of writing this expression?

Comment: @empo which XSLT processor are you using? Doesn't work for me in, for example, XSLT processor built in Chrome or Java Xalan

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two alternative one-liner XPath expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
string-length(@incollection) > 0
```

In case you want to exclude an attribute whose string value is white-space only, use:

```
string-length(normalize-space(@incollection)) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would be inclined to try something like

`select="count(@incollection != '') > 0`

(untested)

Comment: Looks cool, but I thought there might be a function or something  that make it easy to read too